# How to click two button at same time without waiting for each other to process?

Tags: cucumber, watir-webdriver

I have a form with two buttons

[Add to Basket 1]

&

[Add to Basket 2]

I want  to click both at a time and see whether they get added to basket or not.

Each button takes about 1/10 of a second to process

Comment: with slow network speed, the page may not reload immediately..which gives user a chance to click both the buttons...As I am testing the application I am able to do it.

Comment: Did you try my ajax suggestion? With it you can click the button and do the action without the whole page reloading. On a sidenote: The page not reloading immediately has nothing to do with the action actually being carried out. You can not send two requests at the same time, it's just technically possible.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could use ajax for that.
See http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two potential approaches, but it's just theory

1) try using click_no_wait on both of them  it will not wait for a refresh when you do that and the separation of the clicks would be pretty close I expect.

1b) if click no wait doesn't work, see if firing 'onclick' events does

2) learn about threading in ruby, create two threads and somehow coordinate them to click the buttons at the same time.

How a normal user would do this using a mouse t I have no idea, perhaps with a really slow connection it might be possible..